# Mobile Device page navbar overlays the slide show Boostrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slideshow, navbar

I haven't coded a webpage in years and am slowly getting back into it. Trying to update my work's page as it looks way out of date. I'm using Bootstrap 3 and a template "Ruma". I've replaced the majority of the stuff with content I want (still need to tweak some colors).

When I view the site on a mobile device or on Responsinator, the navbar covers the slide show. What would I need to do in order to push the content down so that the navbar isn't overlaying on top of the slide show on a mobile device?

Also is it possible to use javascript to change the logo to a smaller size for mobile devices? I've played with some stuff but have been unsuccessful in my attempt.

Code for the navbar is:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/new_testsm.png" alt="BB" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                 <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="buy.html">BUY </a></li>
                 <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Then starts the slideshow

```
<section id="home" class="text-center">

            <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">

                        <img src="img/bullets1.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption" >
                            <h4 class="back-light">text.</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/ammobig.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption ">
                            <h4 class="back-light">text.</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/boxes1.png" alt="" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption ">
                            <h4 class="back-light">text.</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
            </div>

   </section>
```

For the logo swap I had tried:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
           if ($(".navbar").offset().top >50) {
               $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("small-logo");
               $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("navbar-pad-original");
               $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("navbar-brand");
               $(".navbar-fixed-top").attr('src', 'img/new_testsm.png');

            } else {
              $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("navbar-pad-original");
              $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("navbar-brand");
              $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("small-logo");
              $(".navbar-fixed-top").attr('src', 'img/new_testsm2.png');
            }
         });
```

Any help you guys could offer would be greatly appreciated. I'm slowly figuring out some stuff on my own but some seems to elude me.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you tell me what a jsfiddle is? I googled it but am unsure what you would like me to do.

But I will provide you with whatever you need me to.

Comment: Use http://www.bootply.com/ (bootstrap version of jsfiddle) to create an example of what you're seeing and it'll be easier to provide a solution for you.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/7w98QMq5UE

However, it doesn't include the images because they are local. I'm trying to build it out to work on my machine, test on various devices and then upload as a whole.

Suggestions for the image hosting so you can see it all?

Comment: http://imgur.com/ or http://tinypic.com/

Comment: Ok. I updated it with the images. I threw my bootstrap .css in the .css window along with the style because it wasn't displaying correctly. The logo is still not in the place it is on my local version...

http://www.bootply.com/cBBMufW4Gd

And the stuff on the slideshow is just a place holder. It's also centered on my local version...

http://moose00015.pagekite.me/

Comment: Andrew, thanks that did the trick. Looking at the responsinator, it doesn't push the slide show down on every screen. How do I resolve that? Can you explain what the @media css stuff did? My understanding is it queries whether it is a media device. Then it adds a top margin of 45 pixels.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the help. Much appreciated. I have another question. I'm trying to center a map am unable to do so.

When I change the width to a smaller % or a known distance I can get it centered on my monitor but when collapsing the screen it is no longer so.

Comment: #contact-sec {
  padding-top:6em;
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 
}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JS to swap the image, just use bootstrap to show when in specific views.

Navbar Logo:

```
<a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="index.html"><img src="img/new_testsm.png" alt="BB" /></a>
<a class="navbar-brand visible-xs-*" href="index.html"><img src="img/new_testsm2.png" alt="BB" /></a>
```

The quickfix for your slideshow issue can be fixed via CSS.

Add the following to your custom CSS

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #carousel-example{
    margin-top: 45px;
  }
}
```

The @media tag looks for the maximum width of the devices current viewport, acting as a *if* statement in CSS.

Bootstrap identifies 767px as a "mobile device". Below is the chart that shows Bootstraps information per device. Please adjust as needed
[image: Bootstrap Responsive Chart]